# Create and save duplicate item (with custom option) in cart

Tags: cart, items

In fact just copy and save existing cart item.
Programmatically course.
In cart we have item - "A" with custom option, need clone "A" -> to (create) "B"
"B" full double "A" besides id.

Comment: If you can, please provide some background or more details of your specific scenario along with any code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing.

What you are saying/asking is how to add the field to 'info_buy_request' options, if it was not filled in by a user.

If the user did not fill it in, what exactly do you want to add? The field with NULL as the value? If the field does not exist in the options, then that explicitly means it was not populated, which should be enough, should it not? Why the need to populate it? (and again, with what?)

also, your way of iterating over the item options is not needed. You can get to the data as follows:

```
$infoBuyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest'); 
if (is_object($infoBuyRequest)) { 
    $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(unserialize($infoBuyRequest->getValue())); 
}
```

Now your data is in an object - $buyRequest and can be accessed/manipulated as an object